# How to apply database first approach in Alembic?

Tags: python, orm, alembic

I am new to Python ORM world.
I wanted to generate model (code) from the existing database in Alembic or SQLAlchemy.
I could find any docs about that. Just simply having already created database, I would like Alembic to generate me classes for that database for each table.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Isn't Alembic a tool for migrations? This sounds more like a job for something like SQLalchemy, but i'm not sure it can do this.

Comment: @Kraay89 I'm looking something which is available in .net ef core - scaffolding - code generation for existing database.

Answer (score 0):

Alembic is used for migration. You can read more about it here [Alembic Project Description](https://pypi.org/project/alembic/)

SQLAlchemy is an ORM that translates Python classes to tables on relational databases not vice versa.

This online tool [create-class-from-database-table](https://codverter.com/blog/articles/tutorials/20190715-create-class-from-database-table.html) may help you to get classes from database tables

Comment: it is not compatibile code with SQLAlchemy

Comment: correct. like I mentioned SQLAlchemy translates Python classes to tables on relational databases not vice versa. This is done using [Declarative Mapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_styles.html#orm-declarative-mapping)

Comment: i think this is huge gap in functionality when working with existing database. EF core has got this out of the box. Scaffolding saves a lot of time, especially for large database with around hundred of tables and probably thousands of columns and indices.